# How to overwrite destination in camel bridge?

Tags: java, apache-camel, websphere, spring-camel

I need to send message from activeMQ to IBM Mq and I am using camel bridge in between.Everything is fine. I am able to send the message but at IBM mQ in header part ,
`JMSDestination` is: `Queue:///myQueueName` but my application which is consuming message from IBM mq is expecting `Queue://queuemanagerName/myQueueName`. How to solve this problem. How to overwrite `JMSDestination`.
My routes are like this:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="wmq-to-amq-bridge">
    <route id="amazonMQ-to-websphereMQ">
        <description>Camel Route from amazonMQ to websphereMQ</description>
        <from uri="amazonMQ:queue:activeMQ?concurrentConsumers=5"/>
        <inOnly uri="websphereMQ:queue:myQueueName?preserveMessageQos=true"/>
    </route>
    <route id="websphereMQ-to-amazonMQ">
        <description>Camel Route from websphereMQ to amazonMQ</description>
        <from uri="websphereMQ:queue:test1?concurrentConsumers=5"/>
        <inOnly uri="amazonMQ:queue:activeMQRes?preserveMessageQos=true"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set the JMSDestination as a header before sending the message to IBM MQ.

```
 <setHeader name="JMSDestination">
     <constant>Queue://queuemanagerName/myQueueName</constant>
</setHeader
```